# How to count subarrays in given an array in python?

Tags: python-2.7, multidimensional-array, count

I'd like to find the number of subarrays in a given double array.

For example,

```
Input: aaa=[[4,3,1],[3,1,1,1,3],[-1,-2,3],[4]]

Output: number(aaa) = 4
```

or

```
Input: bbb=[[4,3,1],[],[3,1,1,1,3],[-1,-2,3],[4]]

Output: number(bbb) = 4
```

Could you help me?

Comment: what is `number(bbb) = 4` in the last example?

Comment: I think that your last output must be 5

Comment: I want to say number of nonempty subarrays.

Comment: `sum(map(bool, bbb))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using  simple [len()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) basic python method.